# Passing function as arguments in javascript benchmark [passing function vs direct acces]

Tags: javascript, jquery, benchmarking, benchmark.js

well i'm building some javascript code and im just curious about benchmark of passing function in argument vs direct access

I got following functions

```
testIt(function(){
    alert('Hi test');
});

function testIt(func){
    func();
};

function testIt2(){
    alert('Hi test');
};
```

And now how about testIt vs testIt2? Would testIt be slower?

Comment: Two function invocations take probably more time than one function invocation. However, the performance difference will most likely be negligible.

Comment: testIt and testIt2 are not at all the same function, even if they will perform the same in this example. Apples and Oranges. Since there is no 'not relevant/not interesting' tag, i suggest closing as too broad.

Comment: Why call a `testIt` function at all? Just directly do only `alert('hi test')`, it will be much faster.

Comment: testIt2 function should be faster as testit has overhead of putting another function on call stack.But difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I [test it on jspref](http://jsperf.com/direct-call-vs-anonymous) and here is my result:

Anonymous call have the same speed with direct call.
But creating function on fly work ~80% slower.

So if you want to run some code in cycle — first define function and than pass it anonymously. It give enough readability and speed.